# How to run python scripts with default arguments in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and I would like to ask for some explanation.

My code:

app_code.py:

```
import json
import argparse


def args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Some argumets")
    parser.add_argument("--name", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--surname", type=str, nargs='?', default="Smith")
    parser.add_argument("--birthday", type=str, nargs='?', default="2001")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def create_df(name):
    ar = args()
    print(ar)
    x = {"name": name, "surname": ar.surname, "bd": ar.birthday}

    x = json.dumps(x)

    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args_all = args()

    print(f"name: {args_all.name}, surname: {args_all.surname}, birthday:{args_all.birthday}")
    print(create_df(args_all.name))
```

main_api.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from app_code import *

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/names")
async def root(name: str = 'none'):
    print("In progress...")
    result = create_df(name)
    return result
```

When I run it normally, I mean run just script app by:

```
python app_code.py --name=James
```

I got proper result:

```
{name:James, surname:Smith, bd:2001}
```

But I have problems with arguments when I use it as a FastAPI web application. i.e., when I go to the browser and access:

```
api.addres.url/port/name?James
```

I got that error:

```
 File "P:\pythonProject3\api\.\app_code.py", line 16, in create_df
    ar = args()
  File "P:\pythonProject3\api\.\app_code.py", line 11, in args
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "C:\Users\ubunt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1821, in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
  File "C:\Users\ubunt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 2575, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
  File "C:\Users\ubunt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 2562, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:50671 - "←[1mGET /names?name=James HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[91m500 Internal Server Error←[0m
```

As you can see, I want to have some default arguments and some required to be passed by the user, such as `name`, and I have a problem with those default parameters.

I mean, I know it's because I use in my FastAPI only one method from script (can I just run whole script?), and that's why I put `ar=args()` there. But it  did not fix my problem.

I just want to get JSON created by `create_df()` method, when I just type in browser:

```
`api.addres.url/port/names?James` or `api.addres.url/port/name?James&?Potter`
```

Can someone explain me how to repair it?

Comment: Don't call out to `args` - instead, let your `create_df` function take those values as arguments, and call out to `args` in your `__main__` method instead for the CLI version, and provide values from the web request when handling the API request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that in your endpoint instead. By not declaring a default value for the query parameter, then it **automatically** means that this parameter is **required**.

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#required-query-parameters) (have a look [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#make-it-required) as well):

> **When you declare a default value** for non-path parameters...then **it is not required**.
>
> If you don't want to add a specific value but just make it **optional**,
> set the default as **None**.
>
> But when you want to make a query parameter **required**, you can **just not
> declare** any default value:

So, in your case, you could have something like this:

```
@app.get("/names")
def root(name: str, surname: str = "Smith", birthday: str = "2001"):
    print("In progress...")
    #result = create_df(name)
    return {"name": name, "surname": surname, "bd": birthday}
```

In your browser, you can type, for instance: `127.0.0.1:8000/names?name=James`

Comment: Thank U @Chris , accodring ur advice I just change "result =..."  line to: 

result = create_df(name=name, surname=surname, birthday=birthday)